# Matlab barh bars and legend are not in the same direction

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, legend

When plotting a matrix as multiple horizontal bars in matlab (using `barh`), matlab puts the first column as the bottom bar and the last one at the top.
The legend however, is the other way around, so the first item is the top one in the legend.
I think that looks very confusing. See attached image[image]

```
    data = [0.8000    0.1000    0.6000    0.4500
    0.3000    0.5000    0.7000    0.3500
    0.4000    0.4500    0.2000    0.5000];
    barh(data);
    legend('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4');
```

How can I reverse the legend order?

(Reversing the order of the items in the legend command only changes the strings and not the colors in the legend, so the order is still upside down, and the labels are wrong..)

Comment: Which version of Matlab?

Comment: That's a good question. Octave exhibits the same behaviour, and I haven't found a way to re-order the legend entries. The File Exchange submission `reorderLegend` (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37265-reorderlegend) sounds promising, but it doesn't seem to work with the bar chart. Still, might prove a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
data = [0.8000    0.1000    0.6000    0.4500
        0.3000    0.5000    0.7000    0.3500
        0.4000    0.4500    0.2000    0.5000];
h = barh(data);
legend(fliplr(h),'Column 4', 'Column 3', 'Column 2', 'Column 1');
```

In this way, you change the order of the handles. The legend entries are reordered manually.

Comment: The text is reversed in the legend, but not the colours so it ends up being wrong.

Comment: @am304: thats interesting, since here it works perfectly fine. If the handles are a column vector, the flip does not do anything, but something like `flipud(h(:))` should fix that.

Comment: Yes, the handles are in a column vector, but using `flipud(h(:))` instead of `fliplr(h)` just reverts back to the original legend with `Column 1` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

For stacked bar plots in 2017b you can best use a small function to flip the legend entries: [fliplegend](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67053-flip-bar-legend)

Just plot the bar plot and run this program as you would run the legend:

```
figure();
bb=bar(data, 'Stacked','FaceColor','flat');
labels={'label1','label2'};
fliplegend(labels);
```